# Setting JDBC dataource configurations into an XML

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource

I am using `c3p0` as my JDBC datasource and I am wondering if there is a way to abstract all the connection credentials into an XML configuration file instead of placing it in my java class?

For example, what I currently have is:

```
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass( "org.oracle.Driver" ); //loads the jdbc driver
cpds.setJdbcUrl( "jdbc:oracle://localhost/testdb" );
cpds.setUser("dbuser");
cpds.setPassword("dbpassword");
```

and I am wondering if I can abstract all this out to an XML configuration file similar to how spring JDBC does it?

---

Also, what will be the best practice dealing with multiple different database that have different connection credentials? What I currently have for those situations are conditional if statements, so if you are on a QA environment the credentials are ..., if DEV environment then the credentials are ... and so on. But, I don't think that is very good practice. Can I also abstract the different DB environments into an XML configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a way to abstract all the connection
>   credentials into an XML configuration file instead of placing it in my
>   java class?

Yes you can use the `XML` format of a `Properties` object to define all your keys in an `XML` file and then load it using [`Properties#loadFromXML(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML-java.io.InputStream-).

So for example, here your `XML` file could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="driverClassName">org.oracle.Driver</entry>
    <entry key="jdbcUrl">jdbc:oracle://localhost/testdb</entry>
    <entry key="user">dbuser</entry>
    <entry key="password">dbpassword</entry>
</properties>
```

Then you will load it as next:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)){
    properties.loadFromXML(is);
}
```

From here you can use the methods [`getProperty(key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) or [`getProperty(key, defaultValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to access to the value of your different keys.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is very helpful! So if I have different jdbc drivers to connect to then I will have to create xmls for each one of them correct? Or can I store them in one xml properties file?

Comment: both can be done it depends on your requirements. If you want to have everything in the same file you simply need to use different key names so you can simply add prefixes like `dev` then the key would be `dev.driverClassName`. But in your case I would recommend to have one per env